# Revit View Filter

Tags: revit

I am working on a routine for Revit 2015 shown below. The routine is for selecting an element and creating a view filter that would automatically hide all elements on that system. It only works once in a project due to the fact that a view filter can only be created once in a project and then reused for other views. Does anyone know how i can collect all the viewfilters within the model and compare the name to the view filter I would like to create?

```
public void HideSystems()
        {


            UIDocument uidoc = this.ActiveUIDocument; 
            Document doc = uidoc.Document; 

            Reference r = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element,new SystemElementFilter(),"Select an element of a system");
                if (r == null)
                {
                return;
            }   

             Element elem = doc.GetElement(r.ElementId); 


             var systemNameParam =elem.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.RBS_DUCT_PIPE_SYSTEM_ABBREVIATION_PARAM); 
             if (systemNameParam == null) 

             { 


             } 


             var view = doc.ActiveView; 


             var categoriesWithSystem = 
                 GetCategoriesApplicableForParameter(doc, BuiltInParameter.RBS_DUCT_PIPE_SYSTEM_ABBREVIATION_PARAM); 


             var categoriesWithoutSystemNameParameter = 
                 GetCategoriesApplicableForParameter(doc, BuiltInParameter.RBS_DUCT_PIPE_SYSTEM_ABBREVIATION_PARAM, true); 


             var systemName = systemNameParam.AsString(); 


             // An element can be assigned to the several systems 
             // In this case System Name parameter has a comma separated 
             // list of the systems 
             // Create several rules             
             IList<FilterRule> rules = new List<FilterRule>(); 


             var systems = systemName.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 


             foreach (var system in systems) 
             { 
                rules.Add(ParameterFilterRuleFactory.CreateContainsRule(new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.RBS_DUCT_PIPE_SYSTEM_ABBREVIATION_PARAM),system.Trim(),true));

             } 




             using (var t = new Transaction(doc, "System hide")) 
             { 
                 t.Start(); 
                 string sysName=string.Concat("Remove ",systemName);

                 // Hide elements which are in the selected system                 
                 ParameterFilterElement filter2 = ParameterFilterElement.Create(doc,sysName,categoriesWithSystem,rules); 

                 view.AddFilter(filter2.Id); 
                 view.SetFilterVisibility(filter2.Id, false); 

 vi

                 t.Commit(); 
             } 





        }


 /// <summary>         
 /// Returns the list of the categories what can be used in filter  
 /// by the specific parameter 
 /// </summary> 
 /// <param name="doc">Document on which the filter is applying</param> 
 /// <param name="bip">BuiltInParameter</param> 
 /// <param name="inverse">If true, the list will be inverted. I.e. you will get  
 /// the list of the categories what cannot be used in filter  
 /// by the specific parameter </param> 
 /// <returns></returns> 
  ICollection<ElementId> GetCategoriesApplicableForParameter(Document doc,BuiltInParameter bip,bool inverse = false) 
 { 
     // All categories available for filter 
     var allCategories = ParameterFilterUtilities.GetAllFilterableCategories(); 
     allCategories.Remove(new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_DuctTerminal));
     allCategories.Remove(new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_PlumbingFixtures));
     ICollection<ElementId> retResult = new List<ElementId>(); 



     foreach (ElementId categoryId in allCategories) 
     { 
         // get the list of parameters, compatible with the category.                 
         var applicableParameters = 
             ParameterFilterUtilities.GetFilterableParametersInCommon(doc, new[] {categoryId}); 


         // if the parameter we are interested in the collection 
         // add it to the result 
         if (applicableParameters.Contains(new ElementId(bip))) 
         { 
             retResult.Add(categoryId); 
         } 
     } 


     // Invert if needed.  
     if (inverse) 
         retResult = 
             allCategories.Where(x => !retResult.Contains(x)).ToList(); 


     return retResult; 
 } 
     } 


     /// <summary> 
     /// Allow to select only element what has the parameter  
     /// 'System Name' and has value. 
     /// </summary> 
     public class SystemElementFilter : ISelectionFilter 
     { 
         public bool AllowElement(Element elem) 
         { 
             var systemNameParam = 
                 elem.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.RBS_DUCT_PIPE_SYSTEM_ABBREVIATION_PARAM); 
             return systemNameParam != null && systemNameParam.HasValue; 
         } 


         public bool AllowReference(Reference reference, XYZ position) 
         { 
             throw new NotImplementedException(); 
         } 
     } 
    } 
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a code for a similar task some time ago, creating different views for each category of element, see [original here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2015/04/revit-api-training-and-some-manual-work-automation.html), also copied below:

```
// get the active document from the command Execute param
Document doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

// get all generic models on the current 3D View
FilteredElementCollector collGenericModels =
  new FilteredElementCollector(doc, doc.ActiveView.Id);
collGenericModels.OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance));
collGenericModels.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel);

// but we need the families of these generic models, 
// so let's create a list with the family IDs
List<int> genericModelsFamiliesIds = new List<int>();
foreach (FamilyInstance equip in collGenericModels)
{
  ElementId symbolId = equip.Symbol.Id;
  if (!genericModelsFamiliesIds.Contains(symbolId.IntegerValue))
    genericModelsFamiliesIds.Add(symbolId.IntegerValue);
}

// get the active view
View3D activeView = doc.ActiveView as View3D;
if (activeView == null)
{
  // the active view is required in this case
  // as it will be duplicated with
  message = "Please run command from a 3D View";
  return Result.Failed;
}

// control copy numbers
int copy = 1;

// this list will store the views created
List<ElementId> viewIds = new List<ElementId>();

foreach (int genericModelId in genericModelsFamiliesIds)
{
  // get the family
  FamilySymbol famSymbol = doc.GetElement(
     new ElementId(genericModelId)) as FamilySymbol;

  // create the view by duplicating the active view
  ElementId genericModelViewId = activeView.Duplicate(
     ViewDuplicateOption.Duplicate);
  // and add to the list
  viewIds.Add(genericModelViewId);
  // and open for further processing
  View3D genericModelView = doc.GetElement(
     genericModelViewId) as View3D;

  // here you can adjust the view name
  // according to internal rules
  string viewName = string.Format("MM-{0}", famSymbol.Name);
  try
  {
    // try apply a name
    genericModelView.ViewName = viewName;
  }
  catch
  {
    // should not happen, except for 
    // wrong project standard
    viewName = string.Format("{0} - Copy ({1})", viewName, copy);
    genericModelView.ViewName = viewName;
    copy++;
  }

  // the new view may come without the categories
  // configured for generic models, so let's set all
  // as Visible=false, then set GenericModel=true
  foreach (Category cat in doc.Settings.Categories)
  {
    try { genericModelView.SetVisibility(cat, false); }
    catch { /* não aplicável */}
  }
  Category catGenericModel = doc.Settings.Categories.
     get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel);
  genericModelView.SetVisibility(catGenericModel, true);

  // now create a new filter using the view name
  // and prefixed by F_
  ParameterFilterElement newFilter = 
    ParameterFilterElement.Create(
    doc, string.Format("F_{0}", viewName),
  new[] { catGenericModel.Id });
  // with a rule to show only the family we filter
  FilterRule rule = ParameterFilterRuleFactory.
    CreateNotEqualsRule(
    new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_TYPE_NAME),
  famSymbol.Name, true);
  // and apply the rule
  newFilter.SetRules(new[] { rule });
  // last step is add the filter and set as false 
  // as the Rule is Not Equals
  genericModelView.AddFilter(newFilter.Id);
  genericModelView.SetFilterVisibility(newFilter.Id, false);
}

// finally we have all views, one for each element
// let's export it to DWG files using the view id list
DWGExportOptions options = DWGExportOptions.GetPredefinedOptions(
   doc, "Standard");
doc.Export("c:\\temp_rvt\\", "GenericModels", viewIds, options);
```